# Solve this differential equation using integrating factors: $xy'+y=3xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $$xy'+y=3xy$$ with condition $y(1)=0$.

I got to $y'+\dfrac{y}{x} = 3y$ and the integrating factor of $x$.

I am not sure what to do here since there is a y on the right hand side and the left hand side. If I divide both sides by y I have $\displaystyle\frac{y'}{y}+\frac{1}{x}$ $ = 3$.
I am not sure if this is the correct step to take? What should I do at this point?

Comment: Hint: The LHS of the original equation is the derivative of a product. (Stronger: The integrating factor is already built-in.)

Comment: We get $\int_0^{y(t)}\frac{dy}{y}=\int_1^t(3-\frac 1x) dx$

Comment: @Jochen how do you integrate and put the lower bound into the LHS integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard form of a first order linear differential equation is $$y’+P(x)y=Q(x)$$ so first bring it to that form: $$ y’+\left(\frac{1}{x} -3\right)y=0$$ The integrating factor is $$\large\displaystyle e^{\int\left(\frac1x-3 \right)dx}=\large xe^{-3x}$$

Thus, the solution can be represented as $$xye^{-3x}=\int0dx=C$$ so $$y=C\frac{e^{3x}}{x}$$ and $C=0$. Thus, $$y=0\qquad\forall x.$$

---

Alternatively, you can notice that the DE is separable.
Thus, $$y’=\left(3-\frac1x\right)y$$ so that $$\int\frac{y’}{y}dx=\int \left(3-\frac1x\right)dx$$ so that $$\ln|y|=3x-\ln|x|+C$$ Thus, $$|y|=Ke^{3x-\ln|x|}$$ so again, $K=0$ and $$y=0\qquad\forall x.$$

---

Suppose you don’t like this run-of-the-mill stuff. Notice that $$(xy)’=xy’+y$$So that the equation we have becomes $$ (xy)’=3xy$$ so $$\ln|xy|=3x+C.$$, again giving us $$y=0\qquad\forall x.$$ (Due to @[SeanRoberson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/171839/sean-roberson)’s comment.)